# Recoding dates so overnight hours count as one day

Tags: date

I am working with overnight data (in particular I am concerned about the hours 6PM-6AM). I want this time frame to count as “day 1” for my study. My problem is that the date changes at midnight. Can anyone recommend code to reassign the time-frames that I am concerned about as “day1, day 2, etc.” instead of the Julian date. I am new to this so any suggestions would be very much appreciated!

*Update, here is a screenshot of the data I am working with. So, the column on the left is the julian date.. in this example I am looking at day 305 and 306 and the hours 18:20 (305) to 6:20 (306). I want these hours to be classified as day 1, instead of the date changing at midnight. Also, I need to get rid of the random date that is attached to my time column. I'm sure there is an easy way to do that, but if anyone knows off the top of your head I'd appreciate that!

Again, I'm very new to R and coding language, please be gentle!

Thanks a million.

[image: screenshot of data in R]

Comment: Is any period that starts on day D and ends on day D+1 considered as one day? If that's the case, then the algorithm should not be too complicated to implement.

Comment: Yes, so I'm using Julian date, and military time. I attached a picture of what I want to count as one day... so I have day 305, hours 0-23, and day 306 hours 0-23 but I want hours 18-23 from day 305 and 0-6 from day 306 to all be classified as one. So this would be 6PM from Nov 1 to 6AM Nov 2.

Answer (score 0):

1. You didn't mention what language you're using.
2. Given timespans 6pm to 6am, I believe the simplest solution would be to decrement 7 hours from any given date - then all of your timestamps would have the start day of the timespan as their day component.